# Displaying errors on force:inputField

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Does the `force:inputField` component have functionality to display custom errors similar to how `ui:input*` can display errors using the `v.errors` attribute?

I noticed that there is an attribute on `force:inputField` called `errorComponent` of type `component[]`. Does anyone know how that attribute is supposed to be used?

Comment: Did you mean [`<force:inputField>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_inputField.htm)? There does not appear to be any component by the name of `force:input`.

Comment: Yes, I meant force:inputField. I'll edit the question